# Second to last difference?

Tags: word-choice

E.g. if there are 10 items, 1 to 10, how can I call the 8th and 9th item?

If I translate from my own language (Dutch), I get twice the same result:

```
8     Tweenalaatste    Second-to-last
9     Eennalaatste     Second-to-last
10    Laatste          Last
```

How can I in English call the 8th and 9th item (third-to-last ? ... something else?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In formal language you can use "*penultimate*" and "*antepenultimate*" repectively.  "*Second to last*" and "*third last*" are options usable in more usual language.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/penultimate?q=penultimate)) **penultimate** adjective /pəˈnʌltɪmət/ [only before noun]
> ​immediately before the last one
> *synonym* next/second to last

"**Second to last**" is neither formal nor informal, it's neutral.
This compound word can be used as an adjective, as shows the ngram below.

[image]

There are also the shorter forms "**second last**" and "**second-last**".

[image]

The hyphenless version is more common; the cases for "line"  and "paragraph" seem to show that.

[image]

The form "**last but one**" can also be used but it is less common.

[image]

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/antepenultimate?q=antepenultimate) **antepenultimate** adjective /ˌæntipenˈʌltɪmət/[only before noun] (formal)
> ​two before the last; third last
> • the antepenultimate item on the agenda

"**Third last**" (neutral term) can be used as an adjective.

[image]

The hyphenless version is more common; the cases for "line"  and "paragraph" seem to show that.

[image]

An ngram of comparison between "antepenultimate" and "third last" shows that in fact the first is used nowadays only slightly more frequently.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very elaborated answer.

Comment: A problem with "second to last" is that not all writers are clear on the meaning. I asked a question about this: [Why is "second to last" not documented with the meaning of "third to last"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576404/why-is-second-to-last-not-documented-with-the-meaning-of-third-to-last)